# Collect Flow Stats from Multiple SDN Switches

Tags: sdn, openflow, ryu

I am conducting research that requires the collection of some flow stats from an SDN switch to create input for an RL Agent. I am attempting to scale up my application; however, I am having issues with the time it takes to collect stats and lack of synchronicity of the responses. Does anyone have any advice, suggestions, or insight on possible solutions? More details can be provided, if needed.

I have tried while loops and barriers in an attempt to synchronize.